# How to specify pressed links/buttons in a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

The following is a foreach loop that will show a group of buttons coming from DB.

```
@foreach($acc as $accs)

    <div class="col-xs-1">
     <a href="{{ route('otherP.get', ['p_id' => $post->id , 'op_id' => $accs->user_id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{$accs->first_name}}</a>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

As I click on one of the buttons, I want to show a new view with all same buttons but ONLY the selected button highlighted (e.g. class="btn btn-warning"). If I add the below code in the new view, all buttons will be highlighted, not only the selected one.
Any idea how can this be done?

```
   @foreach($acc as $accs)

    <div class="col-xs-1">
     <a href="{{ route('otherP.get', ['p_id' => $post->id , 'op_id' => $accs->user_id]) }}" class="btn btn-warning">{{$accs->first_name}}</a>

    </div>

    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new property for that button like $is_highlighed in the controller send to the view and in view make an if statement for finding this button

you have two way for this goal
add a new field in DB like is_highlighed (Boolean)
or
you can add a property in the controller
for example, you get a collection from DB by the model and have some values like id, text, color and etc
and you want to make highlighted blue button so in the controller, you check the color and if button color is the blue that adds an is_highlighed = true

Comment: Can you clarify more what do I put in the $is_highlighed property?

Comment: I will go with the DB solution. Can you give more clarification on the idea of the DB solution ?

Comment: you can make a migration via Laravel and add a new boolean field like is_highlited